# If HTML5 local browser database entries exceed its fixed size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have an `HTML5` local browser database which is 2MB in size.
Suppose the entries are inserting one by one or in loop, what happen if the entries crossed the limit of fixed size, which is 2mb?

It is true that the size will not exceed automatically but if the limit is crossed then the top entries which are first entered will automatically be removed to adjust new entries or new entries will stop to insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you exceed your storage it will throw an “QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR” exception.  You can then catch this exception and manage your storage manually